# How to replace a char with a String using its index

Tags: java, string, replace

Hi what is the best way to replace a char with a string : for example :

In my case i have a string containing latin caracters and symbols i'm printing it with intermec printer.I have to pass the code ASCII of the char using the following printer 
instruction :

```
 instruction CHR$(<dec. ascii value>)
```

Example  : 
This text : **N°Box** will be transformed like this :

```
    "N\""+";CHR$(179); \""+"Box"
```

I wrote this :

```
if (!isValid(str)) {
    Map charsAsciiCode = new HashMap();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        String c = String.valueOf(str.charAt(i));
        if (specialCharsMap.containsKey(c)) {
            String decimalString = (String) specialCharsMap.get(c);
            charsAsciiCode.put(new Integer(i), " \";CHR$(" + decimalString + ");\"");
        }
    }

    Iterator iter = charsAsciiCode.entrySet().iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry mapEntry = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
        int charIndex = (int) mapEntry.getKey();
        String charAscii = (String) mapEntry.getValue();

        // Here i want to replace every char with the correspondant Ascii value
    }
}

static boolean isValid(String input) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    return m.matches();
}

final static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{Alpha}+");
private static Map specialCharsMap = new HashMap();

static {
    specialCharsMap.put("é", "123");
    specialCharsMap.put("è", "125");
    specialCharsMap.put("à", "64");
    specialCharsMap.put("ç", "92");
    specialCharsMap.put("^", "94");
    specialCharsMap.put("'", "39");
}
```

Comment: @Henry i want to implement this  //Here i want to replace every char with the correspondant Ascii value.

Comment: Not sure if you can use an external library, but if you can, use Guava 15.0+ and an `Escaper`, it will do the job for you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `Map` as you can do this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i = i+1) {
    char ch = str.charAt(i);
    if (ch > 127) {
        // TODO: generate all the \\""+; crap around CHR$()
        sb.append(String.format("CHR$(%d)", (int)ch));
    }
    else 
        sb.append ch;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two naive ways to go about it:

1. Iterate over each char and build a new string by appending the original char or the transformed
2. Iterate over each mapping, and call `replaceAll` on the String

The two implementations:

```
String replaceCharsByRebuilding(String str, Map<Character, String> mapping) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        String replacement = mapping.get(c);
        builder.append(replacement == null ? c : replacement);
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

String replaceCharsByReplaceAll(String str, Map<Character, String> mapping) {
    for (Map.Entry<Character, String> entry : mapping.entrySet()) {
        str = str.replaceAll(entry.getKey().toString(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return str;
}
```

Both should give the same result, but I think the first should be better.

Answer (score 1):

Below a function `printerString` converts a normal string to a string in the encoding of the printer.

```
static final Map<Character, Character> specialCharsMap = new HashMap<>();
static {
    specialCharsMap.put('é', (char)123);
    specialCharsMap.put('è', (char)125);
    specialCharsMap.put('à', (char)64);
    specialCharsMap.put('ç', (char)92);
    specialCharsMap.put('^', (char)94);
    specialCharsMap.put('\'', (char)39);
}

static String printerString(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        Character specialCh = specialChars.get(ch);
        if (specialCh != null) {
            ch = specialCh;
        }
        sb.append(ch);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

First, `CHR$(123)` is the Basic programming language function call to convert ASCII 123 to a String (of one character). We can achieve the same thing by replacing special (Unicode) chars by their equivalent printer encoding chars.

*For java beginners: it relies on autoboxing - converting char (primitive type) to Character (object wrapper).*